# typescript: how to fix error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: typescript

Given that `directoryToBeZipped` is a string:

```
const destpath = directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1] as string; // The destination path within the archive.
```

gives an error:

```
error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
```

what is this? how can I fix?

Comment: Always read errors, don't ignore them like you are now! `directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)` can return `null`, and if that happens, `directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1]` will error, because you can't do `null[1]`. If you know the match will always exist, you can cast the match result instead with `(directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/) as string)[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways to solve this.

```
const destpath = directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/)?.[1];
```

```
const matchResult = directoryToBeZipped.match(/([^\/]*)\/*$/);
const destpath = matchResult ? matchResult[1] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the MDN reference for the `match` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Note that `null` is a valid return value if no match is found, so the return type is `string | null`